# how to get converted column value

Tags: sql

Our database only provide cad based FX rate (fx/cad), however, I need to use usd based rate(fx/usd); so I want to do something like this

FX_rate_cad_based/FXrate_usd_to_cad as spotrate

---

```
SELECT npv.ValDate, month(npv.ValDate) as Month, rtrim(npv.CurID) as CurID, (npv.SpotRate) as SpotRate_Cad  
 FROM DB.NPVPLFxRate as npv 
 WHERE (npv.ValDate<='2017-03-23')  
 AND (npv.ValDate>='2016-11-01')    
 LEFT JOIN  
 (SELECT npv.ValDate as usdValDate, (npv.SpotRate) as SpotRate_usd  
 FROM DB.NPVPLFxRate as npv 
 WHERE (npv.ValDate<='2017-03-23')  
 AND (npv.ValDate>='2016-11-01')    
 AND (npv.CurID = "usd"))  usdFX    
 ON npv.ValDate = usdFX.usdValDate  
 ORDER BY npv.ValDate, npv.CurID
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Some product specific SQL there...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  cad.ValDate, 
  month(cad.ValDate) as Month, 
  rtrim(cad.CurID) as CurID, 
  cad.SpotRate as SpotRate_Cad,
  cad.SpotRate / usd.SpotRate as SpotRate_USD
FROM DB.NPVPLFxRate as cad 
JOIN DB.NPVPLFxRate as usd ON usd.ValDate = cad.ValDate
WHERE cad.ValDate between '2016-02-28' and '2016-03-02' and usd.CurID = 'usd'
ORDER BY cad.ValDate, cad.CurID
```

I am not sure you should consider `LEFT JOIN`, since your Rates table should have complete information for each day.